# How do I make pass and fail count work in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on this function for one of my classes and my pass count works just fine, however, my fail count ALWAYS prints out 12. I've been reading my code top to bottom and just can't seem to find the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
   
using namespace std;
 
string passAndFailCount(string grades){
  int pass_count;
  int fail_count;
  istringstream myStream(grades);
  string grade;
  while(myStream>>grade){
    int i_grade=stoi(grade);
    if (i_grade>=55){
      ++pass_count;
    }
    else{
      ++fail_count;
    }
  }
  cout<<"Pass: "<<pass_count<<endl<<"Fail: "<<fail_count<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  string grades;
  getline(cin, grades);
  passAndFailCount(grades);
}
```

Comment: What are you feeding your program?

Comment: Ask yourself: What are the starting values of `pass_count` and `fail_count`?

Comment: Aside: why read into a string, then use `stoi` to convert to an int, when you could just read in an int from the stream? Also, your `passAndFailCount` function doesn't return a `std::string`, so why have you declared it to do so?

Comment: `string passAndFailCount(string grades){` why does this function promise to return a `std::string` then violate that causing undefined behavior / making the result of your whole program meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are uninitialized variables.

```
int pass_count = 0;
int fail_count = 0;
```

and you're set.

For an explanation. Non-global variables (which automatically get initialized to 'default' (0) as per the standard), automatic and dynamic variables (like the one you are using), assume the value of 'whatever was in memory at the time of allocating the variable'.

Memory is never empty, there's always 'something' written in there.

So the memory of your `fail_count` variable just 'happened to be' 12 during allocation, which is why you start with that value. This value can be anything within scope.

By explicitly assigning a variable, you 'initialize' the variable, putting it into a defined state (0) and your program should start working as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I should've known better as the professors try to drill this in our head in the intro classes, but I guess I just wasn't thinking.

Comment: @jackson, happens to the best of us. My personal "D'oh!" moment was, when there was a condition that was `if (boolean == true) ... else (!boolean)` and NEITHER case triggered. I was completely stumped, until I fired up the debugger (always a good idea for figuring out what's going wrong) and it showed me a value of '42' for the boolean. :D (Ah, the joys of legacy code)